# TYPO3 - Display system categories and sub categories

Tags: typo3

I am a new typo3 user and actually I'm creating an extension that will allow me to display a list of categories created with the categories of the system, which will contain subcategories (categories and subcategories can have several subcategories), and finally a pdf file

I'm having a little trouble visualizing how to create this extension

Currently, I manage to retrieve and display the parent categories, but I have no idea how to display the different subcategories after clicking on a parent category

Does anyone have an idea how I could display my different subcategories?

there is some code :

```
Controller : 

    public function listAction()
    {
        $categories = $this->categorieRepository->findByPid(177);
        $this->view->assign(
            'categories' => $categories
        );
    }
```

List.html

```
          <div>
            <f:for each="{categories}" as="categorie">
                <f:if condition="{categorie.parent} ">
                    <f:then>
                    </f:then>
                    <f:else>
                        <f:link.action action="list">
                        {categorie.title}
                        </f:link.action>
                    </f:else>
                </f:if>
            </f:for>
        </div>
```

thanks In advance for your advice

Answer (score 1):

Usually the `listAction` never get's any parameters and the `pid` is assigned by the `storagePid` that is automatically fetched by the repository. The repository also can have the setting to ignore the `pid`. You never mentioned it but as I see the `pid` in your code you could also include the option to transfer the `pid` by the URL as parameter.

Additionally, and that's the answer to your question, you can transfer the parent category, so the listAction would have one or two optional parameters. They have to be optional to display also something if no parameters are given:

```php
    public function listAction($parentCategeoryId = null, $pageId = null)
    {
        // HERE SOME LOGIC
        // YOU HAD TO TRANSFER ALSO THE $pageId TO THE REPOSITORY IF USED
        $categories = ...
        $this->view->assign(
            'categories' => $categories
        );
    }
```

The viewHelper can transfer the parameters if you add them there:

```
<f:link.action action="list" arguments="{parentCategeoryId: category.uid, pageId: categorie.pid}" >
    {categorie.title}
</f:link.action>
```

This is no copy-paste answer, so you have still some work, but that's the general approach I'd follow.

Comment: thanks for your answer, for the display of subcategories, do I have to do it on same action list and same template ?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason for the parameter `$parentCategeoryId` of the `listAction`

Comment: It is possible to get the childen of a category? I tried to debug but I can't get the childen of the parent category. I can only get the parent with the childen category